# Get the first four minimum values in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix:

```
X =
     0    81    13    15   100     2
    11     0     6    10   200     8
    19    22     0    20   300    23
```

I want to get the first four minimal values in the whole array `X` with the indices of each value in the array. For example I should get vector `v = [2 6 8 10]` and the index of each value in `X`. 
Also, I want to ignore the zero values when the row number equals the column number.

I have tried to use the `min` and `sort` functions, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following

```
X2 = X;
X2(~~eye(size(X2))) = inf;  %// or X2(logical(eye(size(X2)))) = inf
[val, idx] = sort(X2(:));
result = val(1:4);
[idxRow, idxCol] = ind2sub(size(X), idx(1:4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
vals = sort(X(~eye(size(X)))); %takes non diagonal values and sort the result
res = vals(1:4) %finds the first 4 elements (which are the smallest)
[row, col] = find(ismember(X,res)); %gets the indices
```

result:

```
res =  [2; 6; 8; 10]
```

By The way, if you don't want to ignore all the diagonal values, only the zero ones, use:

```
vals = sort(X(~eye(size(X)) | (eye(size(X)) & X~=0)));
```

Comment: To get the indices (as OP asks for): `[row, col] = find(ismember(X,res))`. Note, I would think Dan's solution is a bit faster than this.

Comment: @StewieGriffin and Dan - thanks for your comments. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This approach has one disadvantage: the `row(1)` and `col(1)` doesn't correspond to `res(1)`.

Comment: @mikhail_Sam - true, if the order is important - using your method (or Dan's) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to [drorco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291841/4960953)'s perfect answer how to find indexes of this first elements:

```
indexes = arrayfun( @(a) find(X==a), res);
```

or if you want to get numbers of rows and columns:

```
[r,c] = arrayfun( @(a) find(X==a), res);
```

P.S. it works perfectly if all elements except zeros in `X` are unique.

Comment: I don't think this works. Firstly `@(a) X(X=a)` is clearly a syntax error so I'm going to assume it's a typo for `@(a) X(X==a)`. Now your first statement returns a vector identical to `res`. Your second is a syntax error because you have too many outputs...

Comment: Ah yes, that's typo of course. Copied wrong line from Command Window. Thank you

Comment: OK it works now, but it's overcomplicating the matter. See Stewie's `ismember` solution for example.

Comment: Agree agree, now I see there are a lot of more useful solutions. By the way I think your approach is better that @StewieGriffin 's method. See my comment to @drorco answer. One more comment - maybe you should add one string of code smth like `result = val(1:4)` :)

Answer (score 1):

Sort all but the ones on the diagonal and then find the indices of the ones which are smaller than or equal to the 4th element of sorted array and not on the diagonal:

```
T=sort(X(~eye(size(X))));
v = T(1:4);
[I,J] = find(X <= v(end) & ~eye(size(X)));
```